# 1214 error when restoring from dump to empty database

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1214

So I'm trying to recreate my developer copy of a database. I do `drop database somedb` and `create database somedb`, so it's all empty. I exit mysql and pipe the dump file into mysql like so:

```
mysql -u root -pfoopassw somedb < newdumpfile.sql
```

Almost immediately I get the following error and the process is aborted:

```
ERROR 1214 (HY000) at line 99: The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes
```

Since I don't have a pre-existing table that can have [a fulltext incompatible type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963534/mysql-fulltext-indexes-problem), does it mean that my dump file is corrupt?

I try to alter the table type (`alter table sometable ENGINE = MyISAM;`) of the two tables that have been created, giving me this error:

```
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Comment: This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228672/converting-table-from-myisam-to-innodb

Answer (score 1):

I've learned that the problem is that I'm using an outdated mysql for the dump file, version 5.5 while I should be using 5.6. I will try to upgrade.

Comment: I used [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-mysql-5.6-on-ubuntu-12.10-including-memcached-plugin) to upgrade (except that I did it for i686). Works fine now.

Comment: I should say that I tried [this tutorial](http://www.denoq.com/2012/02/mysql-5-6-4-on-ubuntu-11-10/) at first but ran into trouble since my*.cnf files [have been moved and changed for mysql 5.6.8](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-default-configuration-file.html) and that tutorial is for 5.6.4. The link in my previous comment is for 5.6.8 though.