# Switching MySQL table from MyISAM to InnoDB - What do I do with the Column Indexes that were FULLTEXT

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, indexing, full-text-search

I am switching some MySQL tables from MyISAM to InnoDB:

What should I use in place of **FULLTEXT**?

As **InnoDB** does not have **FULLTEXT**. 
What should I use in **FULLTEXT**'s place, when switching from **MyISAM** to **InnoDB**?

Thanks all : )

Regards.

Comment: A similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228672/converting-table-from-myisam-to-innodb. In a nutshell `ALTER TABLE tablename DROP INDEX column_with_fulltext;` And then `ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE=InnoDB;`

Comment: Maybe I am not wording this correctly. What should I use in place o FULLTEXT - as InnoDB does not have FULLTEXT. What should I use in FULLTEXT's place, when switching from MyISAM to InnoDB

Comment: You can use third-part application like Sphinx. There is no any built-it mechanism to replace fulltext search.

Comment: Perhaps the answer should be "here is not any built-it mechanism in InnoDB to replace fulltext search"? Can anyone corroborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with MySQL 5.6.4 fulltext indexes are supported for InnoDB.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html